# Angular 8 patch object to [ngValue]

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm using reactive form in my application. I have array of states which looks like `[{id: "3919", name: "Alabama", country_id: "231"},....]`.

```
<select class="form-control input-text" type="text" placeholder="State" formControlName="state"
              (change)="stateChanged()" >
              <option *ngFor="let state of states" [ngValue]="state" >{{state['name']}}</option>
            </select>
```

this works fine . But when I try to patch the value

```
this.driverProfileForm.patchValue({
          state: this.driverInfo['state']
        });
```

It is not showing the state that I'm patching. Can some one help me to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz or show the code that creates the driverProfileForm? and whats the shape of `this.driverInfo['state']`